# how to add xsl attribute

Tags: xslt, attributes, image

I have an xml with img tag

```
<img>
source
</img>
```

I want to generate:

```
<img src="source.jpg">
```

I tried something like that:

```
<img>
<xsl:attribute name="src">
  <xsl:text>
        <xsl:value-of select="node()" />.jpg
      </xsl:text>
    </xsl:attribute>
</img>
```

but it doesng work

Comment: Good question (+1). See my answer for a short and simple solution.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The *reason* why what you are doing does not work is that you cannot evaluate XSLT expressions inside of the `<xsl:text>` element.

[**`<xsl:text>` can only contain literal text, entity references, and #PCDATA**](http://www.w3schools.com/xsl/el_text.asp).

If you move the `<xsl:value-of>` outside of the `<xsl:text>`, then the following will work:

```
    <img>
        <xsl:attribute name="src">
            <xsl:value-of select="node()" />
            <xsl:text>.jpg</xsl:text>
        </xsl:attribute>
    </img>
```

However, selecting `<xsl:value-of select="node()>` for the `<img>` in your example will include the carriage returns and whitespace characters inside of the `<img>` element, which is probably not what you want in your `src` attribute value.

That is why [Dimitre Novatchev used `normalize-space()` in his answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3321119/how-to-add-xsl-attribute/3321148#3321148). Applying that to the example above:

```
    <img>
        <xsl:attribute name="src">
            <xsl:value-of select="normalize-space(node())" />
            <xsl:text>.jpg</xsl:text>
        </xsl:attribute>
    </img>
```

If you get rid of the `<xsl:text>` as [Fabiano's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3321119/how-to-add-xsl-attribute/3321172#3321172) suggests, then you could also do this:

```
    <img>
        <xsl:attribute name="src"><xsl:value-of select="normalize-space(node())" />.jpg</xsl:attribute>
    </img>
```

Answer (score 5):

**Use**:

```
<img src="{normalize-space()}.jpg"/>
```

This assumes the `<img>` element is the current node.

Comment: I'm a recent convert to attribute value templates and I think they're really useful and where applicable make for concise, readable code. I recommend all XSL newcomers to investigate: http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt#attribute-value-templates

Comment: @arooaroo, Yes, completely agreed.

Answer (score 1):

Just remove the tag xsl:text, in this case, you won't need it. Try this:

```
<img>   
    <xsl:attribute name="src">
        <xsl:value-of select="concat(node(), '.jpg')"/>
    </xsl:attribute>
</img>
```

I didn't test it, but it should work. =)

Comment: It would "work", but would include the whitespace text nodes, producing `<img src="&#xA;    source&#xA;.jpg"/>`, which is probably not what @liysd wants. Using normalize-space() as @Dimitre Novatchev suggests would make your answer a valid one.

Answer (score 1):

```
<img>
    <xsl:attribute name="src">
        <xsl:value-of select="my_photo/@href" />
    </xsl:attribute>
</img>

<my_photo href="folder/poster.jpg" />
```