# Calling a javascript function in xsl having some argument

Tags: javascript, xml, xslt

I am new to xsl , i want to call a function podInfo( < agr>) , argument is some attribute value of xml doc which i have captured in my xsl . but the function call is not proper can anyone plz suggest am i right . below is the snippet

```
<xsl:variable name="xx" select="@name"/>
<td>
   <a href="#" onclick="podInfo(<xsl:value-of select="$xx"/>)">
       <xsl:value-of select="@name"/>
   </a>
</td>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `<xsl:attribute>` element, which will allow you to compose `onclick` easily, i.e. by using elements like `<xsl:value-of>` etc.  [Here is the XSLT2 spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt20/#creating-attributes) regarding this element.

It would be something like:

```
<a href="#">
  <!-- xsl:attribute means that instead of putting it's result
       into output document, they will be placed as an attributes
       value of parent element (<a> in this case) -->
  <xsl:attribute name="onclick">
     podInfo(<xsl:value-of select="$xx"/>)
  </xsl:attribute>
  <xsl:value-of select="@name"/>
</a>
```

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3323620/782609) for some additional example.

Comment: Another way could be <a href="#" onclick="podInfo({$xx})">...</a>